# How To wigetized a single view using several models in Yii?

Tags: widget, yii, yii-components, yii-inheritance

Am working on  Yii application, which has only one view -'Dashboard', i need to do all application activity on this single interface. like as show all user details, account, history, status with curd facility.

```
--In Controller--
class DashboardController 
{
    public function actionDashboard()
    {
        $model = new MyDashboard;
        if(isset($_POST['MyDashboard']))
        {
             $this->model->save();
        }
        $this->render('dashboard',array('model'=>$model));
    }
}


-- In Dashboard View --
 // userd-details
 $this->widget('application.components.widgets.addGruopWidget.userdetails');

 //account
 $this->widget('application.components.widgets.addGruopWidget.useraccount');

 //user status
 $this->widget('application.components.widgets.addGruopWidget.userstatus');

 //user history
 $this->widget('application.components.widgets.addGruopWidget.userhistory');
```

So how to define all curd activity for user on this single 'Dashboard' interface using DashboardController. plz suggest solution if possible. Thanks !!!

Comment: What you wrote there could already work, but you don't really need to create widgets if you only show them in one place anyways.

Comment: yep, its a one place, but some of curd facility not workin properly coz we posting multiple data from single view to multiple models. May am going wrong or syntax violation.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function actionDashboard($action=null){

  if(!is_null($action) && strlen($action)>0){
    $method = "run".ucfirst($action);
    if(method_exists($this,$method)){
      $this->$method(); // if $action is 'actionName' then $this->runActionName();
      Yii::app()->end();
    }
  }
}


...
}


protected function runActionName(){
   /*  dp something  */
}
```